# Unable to get scheduled live video using Facebook Live Video API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-live-api

I created a scheduled live video on Facebook live producer. However, when I try to fetch it using `me/live_videos?&source=owner` API, I get an empty list.

I only be able to get the video when it is currently live or the live has ended.

How do I get unpublished live video? I tried filter it with `broadcast_status` but getting the same result.

Can I only see the scheduled live video if it were created using the Facebook Live Video API only?

Comment: Hi Valehelle, facing same issue when getting sheduled live video list but sheduled events  are vsisble on Facebook Content library.Did you find any solution.

Comment: Unfortunately no :(

Answer (score 3):

I'd the same issue this is how I've done it.
You need to append **&source=owner** while requesting scheduled live streams.
Example

```
node-id/live_videos?broadcast_status=["UNPUBLISHED"]&source=owner
```